# how to move the directory contents into an Array in Perl?

Tags: perl

I need to open a directory, read the contents/files in the directory and I've to move all those files in the directory into an array.

I have to do all these things using a Perl Script. Can anyone please give me the code to move the directory contents into an array?

PLEASE FILL THE FOLLOWING SCRIPT:

```
opendir(INFILE_DIR,"$Input_Path") || die "cannot open $Input_Path ";            
my @files =---------------;
```

What will come at the "------" area to move the directory contents into an array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am suspicious that this account is a spam account of some sort take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077309/what-happens-if-multiple-converters-can-unmarshal-xml and there are other accounts that are all prefixed with user[0-9]+

Comment: @Robert - I think that's just what happens when anonymous users ask questions without registering an account.

Comment: @David: Really, well that's just weird. Isn't 'anon[0-9]+' more obvious? Ah well, thanks for letting me know. I retract the above statement.

Answer (score 3):

This will not require you to `chdir` to the wanted directory:

```
opendir my $dh, $dir or die "Cannot open directory $dir\n";
my @files = readdir $dh;
closedir $dh;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
chdir $dir or die "Can't cd to $dir: $!\n";
my @contents = glob("*");
```

Answer (score 1):

After opening a directory you have to read it ([readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html)) in order to get the files.

```
opendir(my $dh, ".");
my @files=readdir($dh);
closedir $dh;
```

Comment: Umm.. Duplicated question with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077282/how-to-move-the-directory-contents-into-an-array-in-perl

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is `readdir`.  You can find more help about using it by doing a `perldoc -f readdir`.