# What happens if multiple converters can unmarshal xml?

Tags: java, xstream

Imean that there might be two or more

```
XXXConverter extends ReflectionConverter
```

that might return true here

```
 public boolean canConvert(Class aClass)
```

for the same class

Answer (score 1):

Only one converter will be used for a class.

If you register multiple converters with the same priority, then the most recently registered one will be used.

Take a look at the source for `DefaultConverterLookup`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess they'd both convert it. But I guess the best answer would be to either look it up in the documentation, or just try it out.