# how to move the directory contents into an Array in PERL?

Tags: xml, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to move the directory contents into an Array in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077282/how-to-move-the-directory-contents-into-an-array-in-perl)

I need to open a directory, read the contents/files in the directory and I've to move all those files in the directory into an array.

I have to do all these things using a Perl Script. Can anyone please give me the code to move the directory contents into an array?

PLEASE FILL THE FOLLOWING SCRIPT:

"opendir(INFILE_DIR,"$Input_Path") || die "cannot open $Input_Path ";
 my @files =---------------;"

What will come at the "------" area to move the directory contents into an array.

Thanks in advance.